# How to set environment variables in cloudcontrol?

Tags: heroku, cloudcontrol

I'm migrating from Heroku to cloudcontrol and I can't find documentation on how to set server environment variables. How is it posible?

Answer (score 9):

There is a config addon for `cctrlapp`.

The following code should do it: `cctrlapp app_name/dep_name addon.add config.free --APPLICATION_ENV=value`

May that help you?

**Edit**: Here is the link to the addon documentation: https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Deployment/Custom%20Config

**Edit:** As of cctrl 1.8.1 you can add config variables this way:

```
$ cctrlapp app_name/dep_name config.add PARAM1=VALUE1 PARAM2=VALUE2 [...]
```

and remove them using:

```
$ cctrlapp app_name/dep_name config.remove PARAM1 PARAM2 [...]
```

Comment: This is right for ruby and java - For python and php you also have to set SET_ENV_VARS=true (cctrlapp app_name/dep_name addon.add config.free --APPLICATION_ENV=value --SET_ENV_VARS=true). This is disabled by default for security reasons, because all addon settings are provided as environment variables. E.g. for php the addon credentials would be visible in the phpinfo().